# Devolver registros de dos tablas con condición de fecha max en una de ellas

Tags: sql

Tengo dos tablas intermedias. La primera contiene los campos típicos de control de incidencias, y la segunda tabla las notas que se están realizando sobre esas incidencias. a modo de ejemplo:

Tabla1: Incidencias

| ID_TICKET | IMPACTO | ESTADO | FECHA_REGISTRO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INC01 | 3 | Abierto | 01/01/2022 09:30:00 |
| INC02 | 3 | Pendiente | 02/01/2022 12:00:00 |
| INC03 | 4 | Cerrado | 02/01/2022 12:00:00 |
| INC04 | 2 | Abierto | 04/01/2022 12:00:00 |

Tabla2: Worklog

| ID_de_Incidencia | ID_WORKLOG | FECHA_REGISTRO_WL | COMENTARIO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INC01 | WL001 | 01/01/2022 10:00:00 | nota 1 |
| INC01 | WL002 | 01/01/2022 10:05:00 | nota 2 |
| INC01 | WL003 | 05/01/2022 11:00:00 | nota 3 |
| INC02 | WL004 | 02/01/2022 12:00:00 | nota 1 |
| INC02 | WL005 | 03/01/2022 10:00:00 | nota 2 |
| INC02 | WL006 | 03/01/2022 10:30:00 | nota 3 |
| INC02 | WL007 | 04/01/2022 15:00:00 | nota 4 |
| INC03 | WL008 | 02/01/2022 18:00:00 | nota 1 |
| INC03 | WL009 | 03/01/2022 17:45:00 | nota 2 |

La tabla 1 se actualiza de su origen cada 15 minutos, y la tablas 2 se actualiza de su origen cada 24h.

Quiero mostrar las incidencias en estado pendiente y abiertas con su ultimo comentario.
He realizado la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT A.ID_TICKET, A.IMPACTO, A.ESTADO, A.FECHA_REGISTRO, DATEDIFF(DAY, A.FECHA_REGISTRO, GETDATE()) as DIFF, B.FECHA_REGISTRO_WL, B.COMENTARIO
FROM [Incidencias] as A
LEFT JOIN [Worklog] as B ON B.ID_de_Incidencia=A.ID_TICKET
JOIN(
SELECT ID_de_Incidencia, max(FECHA_REGISTRO_WL) as max_date
FROM [worklog]
GROUP BY ID_de_Incidencia) AS T on T.ID_de_Incidencia=A.ID_TICKET and B.Work_Log_ID=T.max_date
WHERE A.ESTADO IN ('Abierto','Pendiente')
```

La consulta funciona correctamente, salvo por un matiz. Si se ejecuta el día 4, al actualizarse la tabla 1 cada 15 minutos y la tabla 2 cada 24h, basándonos en los datos de ejemplo, la tabla 2 no contiene ningún registro de de INC04, por lo que no la muestra en la consulta.

¿Cómo podría hacer que se viera ese registro (entiendo que con valor null en los campos de la tabla 2) junto con los otros?

Un saludo.

Comment: Un simple `JOIN` como el que tienes para relacionar la subconsulta actúa por defecto como un `INNER`, simplemente modifícalo por un `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Ya lo había realizado, pero no es el resultado deseado. Al modificar el  JOIN a  LEFT JOIN , me muestra todos los comentarios, no solo el ultimo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más fácil es generar una subconsulta que ya entregue la última fila por cada incidencia, y relacionarla con un `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  A.ID_TICKET, 
    A.IMPACTO, 
    A.ESTADO, 
    A.FECHA_REGISTRO, 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, A.FECHA_REGISTRO, GETDATE()) as DIFF, 
    B.FECHA_REGISTRO_WL, 
    B.COMENTARIO
    FROM [Incidencias] as A
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT  C.ID_de_Incidencia,
            C.FECHA_REGISTRO_WL,
            C.COMENTARIO
            FROM FROM [worklog] C
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT  ID_de_Incidencia, 
                    max(FECHA_REGISTRO_WL) as max_date
                    FROM [worklog]
                    GROUP BY ID_de_Incidencia)
            ) D
            ON D.ID_de_Incidencia = C.ID_de_Incidencia
            AND C.FECHA_REGISTRO_WL = D.max_date
    ) B
    ON B.ID_de_Incidencia = A.ID_de_Incidencia
    WHERE A.ESTADO IN ('Abierto','Pendiente')
```

Cometarios:

- Si tuvieras dos comentarios con la misma fecha, recuperaras los dos
- De acuerdo al motor que uses hay otras formas mas simples de resolverlo.

Comment: la parte del 
```  ) B
    ON B.ID_de_Incidencia = A.ID_de_Incidencia ``` no sobraría?. me refiero, ya se han cerrado los join anteriores (C y D respectivamente).
Al poner el código tal cual, da error.

Comment: No, por que la relación se debe establecer entre la subconsulta y la tabla de incidencias, como regla general, salvo el `cross join` todo `join` debe tener una clausula `ON`